# Sonos SMAPI : AuthTokenExpired faults ignored in getLastUpdate and getMediaUri response

Tags: sonos

We are integrating the Sonos API.
We chose not to implement token refresh and so our tokens last for 1 year until when the user has to reauthorize again.

During my tests, I successfully get the reauthorize popup when the AuthTokenExpired fault is returned while browsing (in response to getMetadata).

But every time the Fault is returned from a call to getMediaMetadata, I get the default error message "Unable to play the radio station". I would expect to see the reauthorize popup instead.

Quoting from [Sonos documentation about authentication tokens](https://developer.sonos.com/build/content-service-add-features/add-authentication/use-authentication-tokens/) :

> If you do not implement refresh tokens, when the token expires, return the Client.AuthTokenExpired fault to indicate the user must manually log in and authenticate again. The Log-Message is a string placed in the log messages for this fault code.

Here is the problematic dialog between our SMAPI server and Sonos application/speaker :

```
31/03/2020 14:24:27 641 SonosApi    Request http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1#getMediaMetadata  "<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Header>
  <credentials xmlns="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
    <deviceId>78-28-CA-9F-86-8E:8</deviceId>
    <deviceProvider>Sonos</deviceProvider>
    <loginToken>
      <token>1fa35465a-6bbc-4cf4-b46f-0e12be5b3216</token>
      <householdId>Sonos_W6VyCDwgI8ZadAWceKQ1avPrtd</householdId>
    </loginToken>
  </credentials>
  <To s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://dev8.local.st-corp.fr:8001/SonosService.svc</To>
  <Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1#getMediaMetadata</Action>
</s:Header>
<s:Body>
  <getMediaMetadata xmlns="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
    <id>14740</id>
  </getMediaMetadata>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>"


31/03/2020 14:24:27 875 SonosApi    Reply   "<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Header />
<s:Body>
  <s:Fault>
    <faultcode>s:Client.AuthTokenExpired</faultcode>
    <faultstring xml:lang="fr-FR">The token is expired</faultstring>
  </s:Fault>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>"
```

Edit:

Refering to the updated documentation and your answer, I should only return AuthTokenExpired fault in calls to getMetadata and getMediaUri.

But what should I answer to a call to getMediaMetadata knowing that the access token is expired ?

Looking at my messages logs, I see that when a user click on a streamable item, the following calls are made in the following order :

1. getMediaMetadata (what would be the answer here knowing the token is already expired ?)
2. getMediaUri (AutTokenExpired should be handled here)

Correct me if I am wrong, but in order to build the call to getMediaUri, the Sonos client use the id returned from the last call to getMediaMetadata, which I can't provide because the token is already expired. Wouldn't it be better to handle AuthTokenExpired first in getMediaMetadata ?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browse (`getMetadata`) and `getMediaURI` calls will respect the `AuthTokenExpired` fault. The re-authorization flow for these calls work as described in the **Refresh expired authentication tokens** section of the [Use authentication tokens](https://developer.sonos.com/build/content-service-add-features/add-authentication/use-authentication-tokens/) documentation. I'll update the documentation to reflect this.

If this does not work, submit a diagnostic to debug it. See [support.sonos.com/s/article/141](https://support.sonos.com/s/article/141) for instructions. Copy your diagnostic number and email it to developer-feedback@sonos.com along with the time window, Sonos household ID, and your StackOverflow username.

You mentioned that when you send a fault in response to `getMediaURI`, you get an error message, but your example shows a `getMediaMetadata` call.

Sonos does not launch the re-authorization wizard when your server returns an `AuthTokenExpired` fault for `getLastUpdate`. When the Sonos speaker makes a `getMediaMetadata` call and it fails, it does not start playback. The user will also see that playback failed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You are right, my description of the problem is not accurate, I will edit my question right now.

Comment: Thanks @syl8o. It looks like there's a bug. Sonos players don't respect the AuthTokenExpired Fault for GetMediaURI when the mimeType is 'audio/m3u8'. Keep an eye on the [developer portal blog](https://developer.sonos.com/blog/) for a fix.